# RDS instance storage is full

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, rds

I have a production instance where storage type is Magnetic. 
Storage of this instance is full.

I want to increase the storage size. I cannot do this since it's magnetic.
[image]

I have to create a new instance to migrate this.
I  don't have the latest snapshot to launch a new instance.

I am not able to take the snapshot since storage is full.

Here is what I want to do:

1. Take the latest snapshot
2. Launch new instance with changed magnetic disk type.

Someone, please guide me how I can do that?

Comment: How did you launch the original RDS instance? The AWS console provides a Restore DB Instance feature that creates a new DB instance from a snapshot. Can you use that?

Comment: I created original instance 3 years ago. To use the restore option I don't have latest snapshot

Comment: OK, it wasn't clear to me that you have zero snapshots (I thought you were simply unable to take a snapshot of the current DB state). Look at either AWS Database Migration Service or Microsoft SSMA. If you create a new DB then either of those should be able to migrate the current DB contents over to the new DB. For example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: What you say "I am not able to take the snapshot since storage is full", what is the error message you receive?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Cannot create a snapshot because the database instance is not currently in the available state. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDBInstanceState; Request ID: 4a04c25e-a675-4f01-83f8)

Comment: What is the **current state** of the RDS instance? Apparently you can try to [shrink the SQL Server logs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190757(v=sql.110).aspx) and that should free-up enough space so that the database is happy again and you can take a snapshot.